# Calculate time in seconds between 2 NSDates

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I cant calculate output from "old" and "now" `NSDate`. Here is the code:

```
NSLog(@"past is %@", past);
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"Now time is is %@", now);

NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:past];
double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;

NSLog(@" Time between is %i", hoursBetweenDates);
```

Here is console output:

```
2015-11-11 18:52:35.608 TaskTimer[2578:130664] past is 2015-11-11 15:52:02 +0000
2015-11-11 18:52:35.608 TaskTimer[2578:130664] now is 2015-11-11 15:52:35 +0000
2015-11-11 18:52:35.609 TaskTimer[2578:130664]  Time between is 0
```

I want to add, that  last value is 0 even when time between two values more then couple of minutes. Why is it 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 33 minutes between your 2 dates, which is a fraction of an hour.

```
NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;
```

That statement is losing the fractional precision, and rounding down to 0, which is what you are displaying.

An alternative is to display in hh:mm:ss format using `NSDateComponentsFormatter`

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute |
    NSCalendarUnitSecond;

NSLog(@"Time between is %@", [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:distanceBetweenDates]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're converting to an integer and it rounds down. Anything < a particular integer value will round down. And a few minutes is < 1 so you'll get 0 hours.

If you want to round to nearest then use `round(distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour)`, or to round up you would use `ceil(distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour)` (though it will also round 2.1 up to 3)

Comment: With your solution, even when i wait 1:52 mins, i got result of 2015-11-11 19:09:38.972 TaskTimer[2970:145877]  Time between is 1, which is odd..

Comment: This statement isn't quite right. The conversion to an integer truncates. It doesn't round. Any decimal with a value of "x.y" will be truncated to just "x". `0.9999` converted to an integer will be `0`.

Comment: If you really want to round the number (as in < 0.5 goes to 0 and >= 0.5 goes to 1.0), then use the `round()` function.

Comment: @rmaddy as far as i know there is different "round" rules in programming, x.y may truncate to x+1 or x, or x,5, depending on that rules.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban You are talking about Objective-C (C). There are very clear and specific rules in place. Converting a floating point value to an integer value through an implicit or explicit cast always results in truncation. If you want different behavior then you have to use the desired function such as `floor`, `round`, or `ceil`.